# Protocol supported by rest webservice

Tags: web-services, rest

I am trying to learn rest web service and every where i found written that rest works on HTTP protocol. I just want  to know what other protocol can be used for building rest service. Link for an example will be great help

Answer (score 0):

REST is 'bound' to HTTP, since the use of the HTTP methods GET, POST, PUT, DELETE is quite central to REST.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, REST is  is a software architecture style for building scalable web services.

You are talking about REST [when applied to webservices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Applied_to_web_services).

> Web service APIs that adhere to the REST architectural constraints are
>   called RESTful APIs.

To answer your question

> what other protocol can be used for building rest service

I first need to clarify some things:

You are asking about underlying web service protocols.
Now a web service is "a software system designed to support interoperable machine-to-machine interaction over a network". The network you are interested in is also the best know i.e TCP/IP aka the internet.

Now you are interested in particular about web services which adhere to the REST architectural constraints.
A REST-compliant Web service would be one who's primary purpose of the service is to manipulate representations of Web resources using a uniform set of stateless operations.

The protocol that  is used for a RESTful web service 
First you need to understand that you are addressing the [application layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer)  of the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). HTTP is an application layer protocol of the OSI model.

Theoretically protocols from [this list(application layer protocols)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer#Other_protocol_examples) which :

- can be used to build web services
- conform to the REST architectural constraints (stateless,layered system)

could be used for a REST-ful service.